# How to highlight everything up to a certain point

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I am new to SAS Enterprise Guide, and I'm beginning to get familiar with some of the useful keyboard shortcuts. I just figured out that Shift+F8 highlights the current step and F8 runs it, but I was wondering if there is a way to set up a shortcut that highlights the current step AND everything before it.

For those of you familiar with RStudio, what I'm looking for is analagous to the "Run all chunks above" option.

Thanks!

I've tried looking at the Macros menu to see if there is an existing option, but I didn't find one.

Comment: I would think of this in the opposite order. Highlight everything from a point BACK to the beginning of the file.  Probably ctrl-shift-home will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CTRL+SHIFT+HOME` will select everything from a line up to the start of the program